# How can I change my Wordpress Woocommerce language?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to set all my website in Spanish

This is what I have attempted as of now:

1.- Setting my general options to Spanish:

[image]

2.- Setting my profile in Spanish:

[image]

3.- Setting my WooCommerce area to Barcelona/Spain:

[image]

This is how "My account" page looks:

[image]

How can I change my WooCommerce language so "My account" and "Cart" pages are in Spanish?

**EDIT:**

As suggested by @Vijay Hardaha I update the question with the Dashboard->Updates content as there are no updates available:

[image]

Also to clarify: I own the website but I didn't make the website myself and I'm a developer but not web/wordpress

**EDIT2:**

Showing with general+profile in Spanish as @Vijay Hardaha commented:

[image]

Comment: Set the language to **Spanish** in General Options then you get the update translations button.

Comment: I have Spanish in General Options, you can see in first screenshot

Comment: In your new screenshot, it's not, so you went to the updates page when you're using the English language, I am saying use/set Spanish then go to Updates Page then you'll see the button.

Comment: hi @VijayHardaha edited question showing how it looks with general options + profile settings in Spanish

Answer (score 0):

If you have not changed the woocommerce template files and edited any text or removed the woocommerce text-domain.

then in the backend go to the **Dashboard > Updates** page then at the bottom you'll see the **Update translations** button, click on that wait for the process to finish then test if you have translated text in your dashboard or not.

**NOTE: if you have modified woocommerce templates and remove the text domain or change the default texts. the translation won't work. because it needs the text domain to match and the text match for translation.**